# XML RSS file format: What is the difference between <rss> and <feed> tags?

Tags: xml, rss

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) and [Landofcode.com](http://www.landofcode.com/rss-tutorials/rss-structure.php) an RSS file should have the following type of header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
```

If I take an RSS feed at stackoverflow.com, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/perl), it has no `<rss>` tag, instead it has a `<feed>` tag at the top of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:re="http://purl.org/atompub/rank/1.0">
```

What is the difference between these file formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is RSS (of which there are [many different, semi-compatible specifications](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/rss/rss-version-history.htm)).

The second one is [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard)), which has a well documented spec and was set up to be a replacement for RSS that learns lessons from RSS but which avoids backwards compatibility to escape the problems with RSS.